# Свой SMTP сервер либо другое решение

Tags: java, smtp

подскажите кто такое делал или сталкивался ,как вы решали задачу
1.Есть коробочное приложение- крутится в докере
2.Нужно сделать транзакционный емайл сервис - тоесть сервис , который будет слать служебные уведомления,всякие там смены паролей и тд.
3.Так как сервис коробочный - то его часто ставят в закрытый контур и тут проблема- внешние емайл провайдеры - работать не будут.
Как это победить? Поднимать в докере свой smtp сервер ( решит ли это проблему?) или есть иной путь
Так же это решение должно работать и просто в открытом интернете

Comment: Если приложение ставят в закрытый контур, то логика подсказывает, что в этом закрытом контуре по-хорошему должен быть свой собственный закрытый почтовый сервер — вот на него и слать, не?

Comment: Тоесть вы предлагаете просто менять хост smtp сервера в зависимости от конутра?

Comment: Тут сразу второй вопрос - если облачные емайл провайдеры предоставляют апи по которому я могу нпример получить информацию дошло ли письмо ,то что делать с серверами в контуре ,ведь как правило это написанный на коленке сервис с отсутствием апи как такогого

Comment: «просто менять хост» — да. Не знаю как там у вас, но лично у меня все используемые мной self-hosted сервисы предоставляют настройки подключения к произвольному smtp-серверу. (Про облачных провайдеров ничего сказать не могу, я ими никогда не пользовался, для моих нужд хватает обычного smtp)

Comment: Может быть я неправильно выразился  сервисы типо SendGrid или Elastic Email